# Changing the image on hover changed the image on entire rows

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I am showing an image inside a `<td>` cell. On hover I am changing the image. But it seems I am doing it wrong.

```
<td class="col-md-1">

  <div class="request-container" popover-popup-delay=200 popover-enable="match.noOfRequests !== 0" ng-click="src.searchSummary($event, match, $index)" uib-popover-template="'./ui-search-result-summary.html'" popover-class="search-result-popover" popover-placement="left-top"
    popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" ng-class="{highlighted: match.isRequestMatch}" id="popOverElement" ng-mouseover="src.requestHover = true" ng-mouseleave="src.requestHover = false" ng-class="{'active': src.requestHover}">

    <span class="result-request"> {{match.noOfRequests}} </span>
    <img class="request-img" ng-src="{{(src.requestHover ) && 'img/sprites/Study.svg#Requests-White-View' || 'img/sprites/Study.svg#Requests-Brown-View'}}">
  </div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.request-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.active {
    background-color: $color-brown;
    color: white;
    text-decoration-color: white !important;
  }
  &:hover {
    background-color: $color-brown;
    color: white;
    text-decoration-color: white !important;
  }
}
```

`requestHover` is a flag which I am setting to `true` or `false` on hover. Could someone help me out?

Comment: The code seems to be fine. But could you share the related scripts and compiled css in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the CSS snippet you are using. I am modifying the CSS, please refer below. Change the image hover to make it work.

```
.request-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.active {
    background-color: $color-brown;
    color: white;
    text-decoration-color: white !important;
  }
  img {
    &:hover {
    background-color: $color-brown;
    color: white;
    text-decoration-color: white !important;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, But this not the issue what i was facing

Comment: Please explain what your problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with a function call on mouse hover just passed the index value on ng-mouse-hover and added a check on image solved my problem.

```
 <td class="col-md-1" style= "padding:10 px">
     <div class="request-container" popover-popup-delay=200 popover-enable="match.noOfRequests !== 0" ng-click="src.searchSummary($event, match, $index)"
      uib-popover-template="'./ui-search-result-summary.html'" popover-class="search-result-popover" popover-placement="left-top" popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" 
      ng-class= "{highlighted: match.isRequestMatch}" id="popOverElement"
      ng-mouseover = " src.requestOnHover($index)" ng-mouseleave = "src.requestHover = false" ng-class= "{'active': src.requestHover}">
      <span class="result-request" > {{match.noOfRequests}} </span>
        <img class= "request-img" ng-src="{{(src.requestHover && src.hoverIndex == $index ) && 'img/sprites/Study.svg#Requests-White-View' || 'img/sprites/Study.svg#Requests-Brown-View'}}">
     </div>
 </td>
```

My controller-

```
vm.requestOnHover = function(index) {
  vm.hoverIndex = index;
  vm.requestHover = true;
};
```